# Signed und Unsigned Integers in Preon

Tags: java, 64-bit, integer, unsigned, preon

I want to use [Preon](http://preon.codehaus.org/) for project that communicates with a server written in C. The protocol depends on the native endianess of the machine (you can solve with this`java.nio.ByteOrder.getNative()` under the assumption that the JVM has the same endianess as the server) and uses `uint64_t` for data lenghts and `int32_t` for status codes (a negative value indicates an error).

I couldn't find information about signedness in the Preon documentation. I had a quick look at the source code and found that `nl.flotsam.preon.buffer.DefaultBitBuffer` uses signed shifts (`<<` and `>>`) and the javadoc comments of several methods in `nl.flotsam.preon.buffer.BitBuffer` also indicate that it uses signed integers, but the javadoc comment `nl.flotsam.preon.buffer.BitBuffer` says that `BitBuffer` uses unsigned integers. This confused me.

What is the default integer format of Preon? How do I represent `uint64_t` and `int32_t`?

Comment: A small point ByteBuffer uses big-endian (network order) by default and can be switched to little-endian.  The native endianess of the machine doesn't matter and isn't concidered.  You can determine the native endianess but if you know what you need, just use that.

Comment: I don't know which endianess I need, but I can easily determine this at runtime via `java.nio.ByteOrder.getNative()`. So endianess is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data marked with @BoundNumber, the default is LittleEndian. You *can* override that like this:

```
@BoundNumber(byteOrder=BigEndian)
```

… but platform specific currently is not an option. That is a limitation. You might want to consider filing an issue for it. (Otherwise, I will, somewhere in the future.)

The way I could see it work is to just have another enum constant, called Platform.

*Update:*

For byte order, Preon now (currently only available in the head) has three options: BigEndian, LittleEndian and Native. Native will resolve in the byte order indicated by java.nio.ByteOrder.getNative().

As a consequence, it is now possible to write code like this:

```
@BoundNumber(byteOrder=Native) int value;
```

… which translates into a signed 32 bit integer, with byte order based on the architecture.

Comment: O, and because of some issues with Codehaus, I am currently pushing to Github, rather than to the Codehaus repository. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hope that will be resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understood it now that default format for integers in Preon is signed. `@BoundNumber(size = "32") long value` could represent a `uint32_t` then. But what about `uint64_t`? Can it be represented in `BigInteger`?

Comment: That would be possible, however it would require registering another CodecFactory that would (in its create(...) method) be triggered by the combination of a BigInteger type and the presence of a BigNumber annotation.